# Socket.IO with HTTPS over apache present?

Tags: node.js, https, socket.io

I have a domain name.

I have a Raspberry Pi as a web-server.

I've edited domain's A record to point it to my server's IP.

Via letsencrypt I got myself a certificate and now website works on https protocol (keeping http on for debug purposes)

I'm working on a messenger app that uses socket.io but using apache+php for low level stuff

So basically apache listens to 80 and 443 and nodejs listens to 3000

Obviously if I visit my site over http - everything works fine and both server and client register connections.

If I visit it over https - Chrome throws **net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED** error (in console when trying to connect to socket.io over port 3000. Site itself loads normally).

Client:

```js
var socket = new io(window.location.host+":3000", { secure: true });

socket.on("connect", function() {
   console.log('success')
});
```

Server:

```js
const io = require("socket.io");
const server = io.listen(3000);

console.log("Server started");

server.on("connection", function (socket) {
    console.log("+USER");
    socket.emit("hello", "Connected");
});
```

I really don't want to use express or anything else for that matter to keep everything as small as possible, especially since I already have a web-server running.

How to properly set it up so users could connect to my socket.io server on port 3000 when they visit the site via https protocol?

**Update**:
From what it seems I think it's a CORS-thing type of a problem. User visiting website over https is trying to connect to an unsecured port (this case 3000) even though it's the same domain? I'd think that would be a no-no for a lot if not all browsers.
A solution comes to mind to just move the whole thing from apache to a nodejs server module and assign manually port 3000 as a secure one via https module but I've no idea how to do it, and I'd really want to keep my apache as a web-server because at least I'm more familiar with it than anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I ended up creating a separate https server that I assume socket.io listens to (?)
Good thing I still have my apache as a main server. I partially answered my question using this post

https://serverfault.com/questions/745248/socket-io-combined-with-apache-ssl-server

**Server**

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const https = require("https");

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem')
};

var server = https.createServer(options);
server.listen(3000);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

console.log("Server started");

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    console.log("+USER");
    socket.emit("hello", "Connected");

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("-USER");
    })
});
```

**Client**

```js
var s = new io("https://example.com:3000", { secure: true } );
```

Hope this is the right way to do it